# React version compability with @pnp/spfx-controls-react

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, taxonomy

Question is, which version of @pnp/spfx-controls-react can I use with React 15.6.2 ?
Is that version of React supported?

I tried with 2.9.0 but when I try to render eg. TaxonomyPicker component, I get following error:

> 'TaxonomyPicker' cannot be used as a JSX component.
> Its instance type 'TaxonomyPicker' is not a valid JSX element.
> Types of property 'refs' are incompatible.

I need package to include taxonomy picker (for managed metadata field) that works with React v15.6.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documented [SPFx development environment compatibility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/compatibility#spfx-development-environment-compatibility), SPFx v1.6 was the last version that was compatible with React 15. Based on the documented [Library Versions](https://pnp.github.io/sp-dev-fx-controls-react/#library-versions) for the React PnP Controls, that would mean you would need to use v1 of the library.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Does this mean that these controls would only work with Sharepoint On Prem and not on Sharepoint Online, if I use v1?